# Is it legal to continue building a route after it has been cut off by an opponent's settlement?

Tags: catan

Say I have a 6 road segment path with only a settlement at one of the ends.

If an opponent were to intercept at halfway and place a settlement, splitting my road in half of 3 segments, can I continue developing (placing more roads, building new settlements) the half which has been cut off from the origin settlement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The rule you might be thinking of is that your opponent's settlement divides the road in two for the purposes of calculating who has the longest road.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.

The rules state that that you must build connected to your own buildings/roads, which you still are in the situation in question.

From [the rules](https://www.catan.com/files/downloads/catan_base_rules_2020_200707.pdf):

> A new road must always connect to 1 of your existing roads, settlesments, or cities. Only 1 road can be build on any given path.

And

> You must meet 2 conditions when building a settlement:

> > (1) Your settlement must always connect to 1 or more of your
> > own roads

> > (2) You must observe the Distance Rule

Answer (score -2):

However, as I understand it (correct me if I'm wrong) you can NOT build a road "beyond" an intersection settled by an opponent.

[image]

Comment: Those rules apply to _new_ roads that aren't already established. In the scenario of the question, the roads already exist and then another player "splits" the roads by building a new settlement. In this case, any new roads would still be connected to other existing roads and are legal to build.